# Proving even and odd pythagorean triples

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, pythagorean-triples

What is the most simplistic way to prove that, in a Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ where $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. If $c$ is even then so are both $a$ and $b$.

Is it necessary to use modular arithmetic or is there another way?

Comment: We need $a,b$ of same parity for even $c$ 

Now $(2n+1)^2=4(n^2+n)+1\equiv1\pmod4$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

every primitive  Pythagorean triple  $a,b,c$ can be generated by:
$$
a=m^2-n^2 \qquad b=2mn \qquad c=m^2+n^2
$$
with $m-n$ odd and $m,n$ coprime.

Comment: And why does this describe every Pythagorean triple?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to keep this fairly straightforward.

---

**Method:** By contradiction.

**Given:** $c=2m$ ($m \in \mathbb{Z}$) i.e. $c$ is even, and $a^2+b^2=c^2$ (let Eq.1)

**Case 1:** Assume both $a$ and $b$ are **odd**. Let $a=2k+1$ and $b=2l+1$ for $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$. Substitute $a,b$ in Eq. 1 and proceed to prove that the new equation cannot hold.

**Case 2:** Assume, wlog, $a=2k$ (even) and $b=2l+1$ (odd) for $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$. Again, substitute in equation 1 and proceed to prove that the neww equation cannot hold.

Since, we have successfully contradicted both Case 1 and 2, the only possibility is that both $a$ and $b$ are even. Q.E.D.