# Pythogorean Triples

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I prove the statement that in a Pythagorean Triple if c is even then so are both a and b. I know someone asked this question previously but those solutions don't make sense so can someone tell me how to do these question.

Comment: "those solutions don't make sense". Please provide a link with a solution who "doesn't make sense".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527327/proving-even-and-odd-pythagorean-triples

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a,b,c\geq 0$ are integers, and that $a^2+b^2 = c^2$.

Note that if $n$ is an even integer, then $4$ divides $n^2$. On the other hand, if $n$ is odd, then $n^2$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $4$.

In total, if $c$ is even, then $4$ divides $c^2$. If either $a$ or $b$ (or both) is odd, then $4$ does not divide $a^2+b^2$, as this sum will leave either a remainder of $1$ or $2$ when divided by $4$. Thus both $a$ and $b$ have to be even.

Comment: why did you use 4

Comment: I used the number $4$, because I know that $4$ is a good tool for dividing squares into even and odd numbers by looking at their remainder.

Comment: @SyedNaqi  Observe that if $n$ is even, then $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$.  Hence, if $n$ is even, then $n^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2$ is divisible by $4$.  If $n$ is odd, then $n = 2k - 1$ for some integer $k$.  Hence, if $n$ is odd, then $n^2 = (2k - 1)^2 = 4k^2 - 4k + 1 = 4(k^2 - k) + 1$ has remainder $1$ when divided by $4$.